# Modern modeling approaches for tabular data with both text and numeric fields?

Tags: classification, boosting, word-embeddings, transformers

I am doing binary classification on tabular data. Each record in a table has one text field of variable length (typically <3k characters, the longest is 50k) and ~150 numeric fields (these are aggregate features I constructed myself, there are no mandatory features I have to use).

An old-school way would be to represent text as a bag of words (eg tf-idf) and feed it into a model like logistic regression or gradient boosting alongside numeric fields. Now, today we have text embeddings. If I didn't have numeric features I would employ some BERT-like model for text classification. So here's the choice.

1. I can still feed embedding vectors (perhaps "compressed" via PCA) into gradient boosting like a set of separate numeric features -- it works, and this approach is mentioned in catboost [examples](https://github.com/catboost/tutorials/blob/master/events/2020_11_18_catboost_tutorial/text_embedding_features.ipynb).
2. I can cast all numeric fields as a text and feed it into some transformer model alongside proper text field (in [T5's fashion](https://arxiv.org/abs/1910.10683)). I am not sure about this approach, since I don't have much data (~180k records -- it might be enough for fine-tuning, but feeding numeric fields seems to imply training from scratch, so that the model learns the meaning of this particular numeric layout).
3. I can use BERT-like model and gradient boosting separately -- for text and numeric fields respectively and then combine them in some way. Here the issue is that I am not sure which  features of the whole record are responsible for its label. It might be that a record belongs to a positive class, but not due to its text, in which case I don't know how to label this text for BERT training. Same for numeric features. It seems more reasonable to either use output/ intermediate representations from BERT in a downstream boosting model or train them simultaneously in such a way that the error backpropagates properly.
4. Some other approach I don't know of.

My primary concern is classification performance (inference/training time is not important).

Thank you!